# jQuery .click function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a paragraph to fade out when the button is clicked, and I also need another paragraph to fade in at the same time. I've tried everything I can think of, even formatting differently, but nothing works. My code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.s3').addClass('.one');
$('.button1').addClass('.party');
$('.button2').addClass('.bear');
$('.button1').click(function(){
    $('.one').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.ifparty').fadeIn('slow',1);
});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant to add a class of "one" not ".one".  Your selector is not going to pick that up the way you are adding it now.  Same with the other addClass() calls.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.s3').addClass('one');
$('.button1').addClass('party');
$('.button2').addClass('bear');
$('.button1').click(function(){
    $('.one').fadeOut(200);
    $('.ifparty').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

[A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/seano666/RrfBN/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7Gcjp/1/

You dont need to . with class name while adding a class to element.

```
$('.s3').addClass('one');
```